# How to call `quoteExactInputSingle` on quoter2 uniswap using python

Tags: uniswap, python, brownie, uniswapv3, ape

I'm trying to call like this in `ape`

```py
def SushiswapV3quoteExactInputSingleV3(
    router,
    _from,
    tokenIn: str,
    tokenOut: str,
    fee: int,
    amountIn: int,
    sqrtPriceLimitX96: int = 0,
) -> int:

    # fee = 3000  # 0.3%

    params = {
        "tokenIn": tokenIn,
        "tokenOut": tokenOut,
        "amountIn": amountIn,
        "fee": fee,
        "sqrtPriceLimitX96": sqrtPriceLimitX96,
    }
    # params = (
    #     tokenIn,
    #     tokenOut, 
    #     amountIn,
    #     fee,
    #     sqrtPriceLimitX96
    # )
    

    (
        amountsOut,
        sqrtPriceX96After,
        initializedTicksCrossed,
        gasEstimate,
    ) = router.quoteExactInputSingle.call(params, sender=_from)
    # amountsOut = router.quoteExactInputSingle.call(
    #     tokenIn, tokenOut, fee, amountIn, sqrtPriceLimitX96, sender=_from
    # )

    return amountsOut
```

But the transaction is keep getting failed.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that a pool with that fee exists.

The fee changes which pool for the address-pair, will be traded on.
If having issues check the pool(s) being routed through to make sure they exist and have the liquidity you expect.

```
>>> USDC_ADDRESS
'0x2791Bca1f2de4661ED88A30C99A7a9449Aa84174'
>>> WMATIC_ADDRESS
'0x0d500B1d8E8eF31E21C99d1Db9A6444d3ADf1270'
>>> FEE
500
>>> AMOUNT_IN
1000000
>>> SQRT_PRICE_LIMIT
0
>>> AMOUNT_OUT = quoter.functions.quoteExactInputSingle(USDC_ADDRESS, WMATIC_ADDRESS, FEE, AMOUNT_IN, SQRT_PRICE_LIMIT).c all()
>>> AMOUNT_OUT/10**18
1.7623184027165504
>>>
```

Comment: Looks like there is no pool for `DAI/WETH`. If that's the case then how can we swap these tokens using the UI?

Comment: how can we see if a pool exists or not ?

Comment: Using the UI you should be able to just enter the tokens and it will find a route through pools which do have liquidity.
Use app.sushi.com rather than www.sushi.com if you would like to force v2.

Use getPool() at the factory contract to check if a pool exists:
https://polygonscan.com/address/0x917933899c6a5F8E37F31E19f92CdBFF7e8FF0e2#readContract

Comment: How come there is no `DAI/WETH` pool but still we can do the swap from UI? Is there a way to achieve this using smart contracts?

Comment: You can use the v2 pool, there is about 300k: 
https://polygonscan.com/address/0x6FF62bfb8c12109E8000935A6De54daD83a4f39f
Or go from one, to wmatic, then wmatic the other, something like that might get the best deal.

There are many examples of using the v2 router, which is the simplest method: 
https://polygonscan.com/address/0x1b02da8cb0d097eb8d57a175b88c7d8b47997506
swapExactTokensForTokens() or swapTokensForExactTokens()